# how char * (*arr)[2 ] and char **array[2] are different from each other?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string, pointers

how `char * (*arr)[2]` and `char **array[2]` are different from each other ?? if I am passing `char* strings[2]` using a function then how to access the elements from both the ways mentioned in first part of question?
Please also tell other ways to access elements of pointer array also.
Thanks.

Comment: In C? Or in C++?

Comment: One is an array, the other is a pointer to an array.

Comment: Your headline and your question don't match. Please correct one.

Comment: @chrylis: He just forgot (or didn't know) to enclose his code in back ticks.  It was the same.

Comment: @chrylis: I added no `*`.  I only added the backticks, which made the asterisks appear correctly.

Comment: Never mind, I see the issue; SO grabbed the trailing `*`.

Comment: It would be helpful to mention the language in title or at least in the question, as the latter is clearly language dependent.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev: That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html):-

**a]  char *(*arr)[2]**

```
        +------+
        | +--+ |
        | |  | |
        | ^  | |
char * (*arr ) [2] 
     |  |    | |
     |  |    | |
     |  +----+ |
     +---------+

identifier arr is pointer 
            to array of 2
            pointer to char
```

**b] char **arr[2]**

```
      +----------+
      | +----+   |
      | ^    |   |
char* *arr   [2] |
    | |      |   |
    | +------+   |
    +------------+


identifier arr is an array 2
            of pointers
            to pointer
            to char
```

Similarly,

**c] char* strings[2]**

```
                    +-----+
                    |     |
                    ^     |
            char *strings [2]
                 |        |
                 +--------+

 identifier string is an array of 2
            pointers 
            to char
```

So, know figure out the differences

Comment: This is great!! Please fix the first diagram which is wrong -- first to pointer then to array (within the `()`)  Like this: https://gist.github.com/hoganlong/6413843

Comment: @Hogan sorry could you plz fix it, I didn't get what you mean

Comment: @Hogan ahh, I think it's same see now I used start marker `^`

Comment: @POW - I see what you mean.. I made a small change so the first thing it hits is the `*` -- what do you think?

Comment: @POW - Ok I changed it back, I see what you mean, not how I think about it.

Answer (score 12):

[CDecl](http://cdecl.org) reports:

```
char *(*arr)[2]

declare arr as pointer to array 2 of pointer to char
```

and

```
char **arr[2]

declare arr as array 2 of pointer to pointer to char
```

It's just that the `[]` array declarator has higher precedence than the `*` pointer qualifier, so parentheses change the meaning.

Comment: Dang, a website did it.  I feel silly for knowing the order of evaluation rules.

Comment: @Hogan I see no order-of-evaluation problems here. It's a matter of precedence. Nothing is evaluated. Declarations are statements, not expressions.

Comment: ???? @H2CO2 -- I was not saying there was a problem.  I guess technically I used the term 'order of evaluation' and not precidence - but why are you sniping at my silly comment said in fun?

Comment: @Hogan Sorry, I didn't realize it was fun. Also, it's a common source of confusion that some think that precedence == order of evaluation. It isn't, though - think of the `&&` and `||` operators (there are quite a lot of questions about that problem on SO, read one of them if you're interested.)

Answer (score 5):

`char * (*arr)[2]` is a pointer to an array of pointers.

`char **array[2]` is an array of pointers to pointers.

> if I am passing `char* strings[2]` using a function then how to access the elements from both the ways mentioned in first part of question?

`strings` is an array of pointers, so `&strings` gives the first type. You can't get the second type from that.

In C++, I would recommend you stop messing around with strange compound types, and use higher level array-like classes such as `std::vector` and `std::string` instead.

Answer (score 2):

`char **array[2]` is a 2 element array of pointers to pointers to character.

`char *(*arr)[2]` is a pointer to a two element array of pointers to character.

nb.  pointers to character can be used as a string in C when null terminated.

Answer (score 1):

The rule I've always found useful is "inside out, right to left":

```
char *(*arr)[2];
```

So inside first, the paren group has '*arr", right to left is "arr is a pointer"

nothing left in parens, so "arr is a pointer" to the rest of it, right to left:  an array of two pointers to char.

A similarly short rule I've always found useful is to say that "the value of a C array is a pointer to its first element" -- which also highlights the distinction between uses of a name for its value and for other attributes: `f(arr)` and `arr+1` both use `arr`'s value, and its value in each of those is a pointer to its first element (with its array-ness and bounds stripped), but e.g. `sizeof arr` doesn't evaluate and so gives the array size.